# how to use MFC for real work in VC2008

Tags: user-interface, mfc, visual-c++-2008

my backgrounds are C/python/pyqt, and I was forced to use MFC for GUI programming(by my boss, in the consideration that he can assign this job to others in the future). and I encountered this problems:

- how to create a tab control (found one solution on internet)
- how to create a table view
- how to use json, sqlite or other third party library
- how to embed a web browser
- how to draw plot by using double buffer
- how to do exception/assert/unittest/profile/

So is there a book or site collect stuff in this subjects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website with most MFC stuff is www.codeproject.com.

Answer (score 0):

Books on MFC are a bit thin on the ground these days. The standard work was by Jeff Prosise (Programming Windows with MFC, or Programming Windows 95 with MFC according to what issue you got) but that's out of print. Amazon has second hand copies for sale.

The answer to your questions tends to vary whether you're using Documents and Views or dialog based applications. I suspect the easiest way to do a tab control would be to put a tab into a dialog resource and create a CFormView. Same with a web browser, though the browser controls that shipped with MFC were a bit primitive, last time I checked (that was a few years ago though). The SQLite issue is addressed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843303/sqlite-with-mfc)